# DockerHub Automated Build Failure

Tags: docker, boot2docker, dockerhub

I have a Dockerfile which builds without failure locally. I threw it up on Dockerhub and i can pull it from any machine and run it successfully. When i attempted to create an automated build which was linked to a git repo, the build began to fail. Sometimes it is successful, other times it's not. Also, I have the option to update the rebuild the image once a push has been made. So, whenever a push is made Dockerhub queues four builds. Why is that? And most of them return errors saying "Failure to get session". I don't understand why.

[image: Arbitrary success or error]

Comment: There might be a difference of docker versions, have you checked that ?

Comment: docker version on local machine asserted against version on dockerhub?

Comment: yes, online services tend to have older versions

Comment: client and server are both 1.12.3